# Handle back press when returned from browser to application in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, browser

I am developing an application and am stuck in a part. I have to call a browser with some URL. When user is done with his stuff on the browser then he can return to the application by back press.
Is there some way to call a specific activity once user is back in the application.

---

#### Solved

Solved this by calling the activity in onResume of browser calling activity and clearing the back stack.

Comment: there is alos backkey listnear in android

Comment: if your activity is still in stack,then on back press, user will automatically navigate to your app.

Comment: Stella ,you are correct

Comment: switching to another app from your own will fire onPause in your activity, if you back from any other app or your activity still in stack onResume will fire, this is the place where you track

Comment: when you start browser using intent then do not call finish().

Comment: Actually i have to call a different activity once i get back to the browser calling activity. Lets say Activity A calls the browser when user presses back button, it should not get back to Activity A, it should call Activity B,and if i am not wrong it can be acheived by calling Activity B in onResume() of Activity A.

Answer (score 0):

*If your activity is still in stack,then on back press, user will automatically navigate to your app.*

To make sure your activity is no still in stack, **Don't finish** the activity while starting new activity with intent to open the browser.